# Python 2: global variable being changed in a function isn't updating to the new value

Tags: python-2.7

Sorry if the title is confusing. And if I'm using the wrong terms. I just started coding last week.

I'm writing a dice roll function for the boss battle of a text adventure game and while I can get the the dice function to use the original global variable outside the function, subtract a number and report it within the function, it doesn't update the global variable after the function runs. So the next time I try to call the function, it uses the original value again, which completely defeats the purpose of having the dice there in the first place.  (You can't ever kill the boss, lol)

Here's what I've been playing with trying to debug.  Thanks in advance!

```
player = "Dib"
playerhealth = 3
boss = "Zim"
bosshealth = 5

import random

def dice(who, whohealth):
    min = 1
    max = 3
    dice = random.randint(min, max)

    if dice == 1:
        print "Your opponent lost no health"
        print "Your opponent has %d health" % whohealth
    elif dice == 2:
        print "%s hits" % who
        whohealth = whohealth - 1
        print "Your opponent lost 1 health"
        print "Your opponent has %d health" % whohealth
    elif dice == 3:
        print "%s crits" % who
        whohealth = whohealth - 2
        print "Your opponent lost 2 health"
        print "Your opponent has %d health" % whohealth
    else:
        print "stuff"

dice(player, bosshealth)
dice(player, bosshealth)

dice(boss, playerhealth)
dice(boss, playerhealth)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, btw! Don't forget to mark an answer as correct by clicking the check mark!

Answer (score 0):

You never returned `whohealth` back; Python passes objects by reference, but you are rebinding the reference in the function:

```
whohealth = whohealth - 1
```

That assigns a new value only to the local name `whohealth`; the original reference is not updated.

The best way to deal with this is by *returning* the new value:

```
def dice(who, whohealth):
    min = 1
    max = 3
    dice = random.randint(min, max)

    if dice == 1:
        print "Your opponent lost no health"
        print "Your opponent has %d health" % whohealth
    elif dice == 2:
        print "%s hits" % who
        whohealth = whohealth - 1
        print "Your opponent lost 1 health"
        print "Your opponent has %d health" % whohealth
    elif dice == 3:
        print "%s crits" % who
        whohealth = whohealth - 2
        print "Your opponent lost 2 health"
        print "Your opponent has %d health" % whohealth
    else:
        print "stuff"

    return whohealth

bosshealth = dice(player, bosshealth)
bosshealth = dice(player, bosshealth)

playerhealth = dice(boss, playerhealth)
playerhealth = dice(boss, playerhealth)
```

Now the function returns the new health value, and you can assign that value back to the `bosshealth` or `playerhealth` globals.

Answer (score 0):

Not to try and rewrite things, but here is an alternate way to go about it using dictionaries.

```
player = {
  'name' : "Dib",
  'health' : 3
}
boss = {
  'name' : "Zim",
  'health' : 5
}

import random

def attack(attacker, attacked):
    min = 1
    max = 3
    dice = random.randint(min, max)

    if dice == 1:
        print "Your opponent lost no health"
        print "Your opponent has %d health" % attacked['health']
    elif dice == 2:
        print "%s hits" % attacker['name']
        attacked['health'] -= 1
        print "Your opponent lost 1 health"
        print "Your opponent has %d health" % attacked['health']
    elif dice == 3:
        print "%s crits" % attacker['name']
        attacked['health'] -= 2
        print "Your opponent lost 2 health"
        print "Your opponent has %d health" % attacked['health']
    else:
        print "stuff"

attack(player, boss)
attack(player, boss)

attack(boss, player)
attack(boss, player)
```

Comment: No, Python passes references around, but the function *rebinds* the reference.

Comment: Interesting... So you're saying that if you declare `global bosshealth` inside the `dice` function that `whohealth` _will_ work to update the global?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `whohealth` is a reference to the same *value* as `bosshealth` is bound to. Until you create a new value and bind `whohealth` to that.

Comment: In Python everything is an object; treat them like balloons and anything that refers to them (variables, attributes on objects, keys and values in dictionaries, entries in lists, etc.) as labels with strings. If you retie the label to another balloon you cut the string to the first value.

Comment: So can you do some kind of dereferencing in Python to make sure you _do_ update the value instead of simply pointing at a new one?

Comment: You could pass in a mutable object, like a dictionary, or a list or another object. Then you can reach in and change the references *inside* that object. A list is like a big blimp with numbered labels; you have a label tied to the blimp all this time, but you can tell the blimp itself to retie labels too.

Comment: Just looked it up. Primitives are immutable. I'm set straight now. :)

Comment: Oh cool.  I hadn't learned about dictionaries yet.  I've been learning at work with the Learn Python the Hard Way courses, but when I got to lesson 35, I decided to try to make a game for poops and giggles.